Why is this caching of an .ejs file not working?
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if(myCache.has('/')){
        console.log('Getting it from cache....')
        return res.send(myCache.get('/'))
    }else{
        let htmlStr = '';
        res.renderFile('index', {title: 'ReSt ApI'}, (err, html) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('Error');
            }
            else{
                htmlStr = html;
                myCache.set('/', htmlStr)
                res.send(htmlStr);
            }
        })
    }
})

I am using standart node-cache syntax, but the server does not respond to root URL in this case. How can I modify the code so that it worked? For comparison, here's the routing of a standart html file without templating and it perfectly works:
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if(myCache.has('/')){
        console.log('Getting it from cache')
        return res.sendFile(myCache.get('/'))
    } else{
        myCache.set('/', path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'))
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'))
    }
})


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just as the @Community Bot says, it's not clear what you are asking, we only know that caching of an .ejs file is not working. What exactly is not working? Does it not correctly save the cached data, does the page loaded from the cache not render, etc.? Furthermore, if your goal is to display EJS/HTML files and not to actually send (download) a file, you need to use res.render('path/to/ejsPage') or render it beforehand and send the HTML string (but with res.send(html) and not res.sendFile(html)).

Also, your caching seems kind of... unnecessary? For the HTML file, you are simply mapping routes to file paths, but ultimately in the if and else block the same thing happens, except for where you get the file path from (which in the grand scheme of things makes about zero difference). As for the EJS files, what you are doing makes only sense if the page always stays the same, pretty much like an image. Which defeats the purpose of using EJS in the first place: to render templates with varying variables and thus being able to have different HTML markup depending on the variables.
